# MySQL wrong ORDER BY for hungarian characters

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, special-characters, collation

I run the following query:

```sql
SELECT name FROM shops ORDER BY name;
```

The current result:

```
ABC shop
ÁDE shop
ALT shop
```

Expected result should be:

```
ABC shop
ALT shop
ÁDE shop
```

Looks like `A` and `Á` are equal. (Correct order: a < á < e < é < o < ó < ö...)

**I tried to use hungarian collation (with mysql 8.0.17):**

```sql
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci;
```

*I found that the mysql team have fixed this issue in mysql 8.0.1: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12519*

**SHOW CREATE TABLE shops;**

```
| shops | CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_category_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_chain_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `partner_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `deputy_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `shops_address_id_foreign` (`address_id`),
  KEY `shops_shop_category_id_foreign` (`shop_category_id`),
  KEY `shops_shop_chain_id_foreign` (`shop_chain_id`),
  KEY `shops_partner_id_foreign` (`partner_id`),
  KEY `shops_location_id_foreign` (`location_id`),
  KEY `shops_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `shops_deputy_user_id_foreign` (`deputy_user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `shops_address_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `shops_deputy_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`deputy_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `shops_location_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `shops_partner_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `shops_shop_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_category_id`) REFERENCES `shop_categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `shops_shop_chain_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_chain_id`) REFERENCES `shop_chains` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `shops_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=564 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Have a look at custom ordering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768594/how-to-order-by-custom-rule-e-g-how-to-order-like-4-2-1-3

Comment: @Strawberry question has been updated.

Comment: @BrettGregson this custom ordering looks a little hacky, but I will try it

Comment: Why the PHP tag? Your issue is independant to that, unless you want to sort in PHP.

Comment: @AmigoJack true. I removed it.

Comment: have you tried `ORDER BY BINARY name` ?

Comment: @Peter Kota Not an expert, but isn't it be utf8mb4_hu_0900_as_cs Accent Sensitive and case sensitive.. so that it treats a < á differently

Comment: utf8mb4_is_0900_ai_ci may be a viable workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No simple solution:

Plan A:  Write your own collation.

Plan B:  Write a bug at bugs.mysql.com complaining that even in 8.0.17, `utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci` is "incorrect".

(Meanwhile, I suspect `utf8mb4_hungarian_ci` was left with the 5.7 collation for backward compatibility.)

Comment: I saw your comment on the bug report; but it seems that the Hungarian collation rules itself are pretty ambiguous. Going through the first comment, where the "rules" are defined, it says: "In general, when ordering or comparing, the short and the long version should be treated as equal, except when the order cannot be decided by the characters after the vowel."

Comment: Hard to imagine that this is not working in mysql.. Create an own collation sounds great. I will try it. Thank you @RickJames

Answer (score 3):

The question itself is wrong. The expected result is:

```
ABC shop
ÁDE shop
ALT shop
```

and it's right.

https://helyesiras.mta.hu/helyesiras/default/akh12#F2_4